# How to count a text input and sort by occurence with total in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

I just started Spark/Scala learning.

I understand this is a common question and most likely have been answered somewhere already, but hopefully can get someone's help on my following practice:

I tried to get a wordcount 
1. sorted by total occurrence for each word in desc
2. sorted by the word itself in alphabetic order

Here is the code:

```
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Peter")
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
.map(word =>(word, 1))
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.sortByKey(true, 1)
```

Here is part of the result:
[image]

My questions:

1. Is this a correct result? How do I verify it? It doesn't look like a correct result to me, for example, why the first one is "1", and I presumably think words like "an", "of", "the" should be on the top, wouldn't they?
2. I want to include the total count (desc) of each word after the word in the result
3. I also want to see another sorted result by the word in alphabetical order

Can anyone please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post or upload the contents of the text file you are using?

Comment: Thanks. Romero, you can find the text file here: https://sites.google.com/site/ruwach/bibletext, what I was working on is NewTestament and 1_2Peter, there are 8 small text files for it, I combined them into one file called Peter.txt, and then loaded it to HDFS for scala to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sortByKey in your code is the word in ascending order. That's why 1 is on the top.

In order to get most common words
    val file = sc.textFile("peter.txt")

```
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .map(word =>(word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_+_)

// from word -> num to num -> word
// then sortBy num of occurrence in descending order 
val mostCommon = counts.map(p => (p._2, p._1)).sortByKey(false, 1)
mostCommon.take(5)
```

get result like

```
Array((263,the), (182,of), (119,and), (91,that), (80,in))
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Yang, can you please post the full script? I tried this and it is not working: val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
.map(p => (p._2, p._1))
.sortByKey(false, 1)

Answer (score 0):

This is my text file data

```
nilesh shinde nileshshinde indian
nilesh love india
i am indian
swati nilesh
```

In Following spark-shell code I will give you the required output

```
    scala> var rdd=sc.textFile("/user/hadoop/data/sample.txt")  

    scala> val listofword=rdd.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))

    scala> val numberofword=listofword.map(x =>(x,1))

    scala> numberofword.reduceByKey(_+_).toDF.sort($"_2".desc).show
+------------+---+
|          _1| _2|
+------------+---+
|      nilesh|  3|
|      indian|  2|
|       india|  1|
|           i|  1|
|          am|  1|
|nileshshinde|  1|
|      shinde|  1|
|        love|  1|
|       swati|  1|
|            |  1|
+------------+---+
```